# Are there punishments for not playing for awhile?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've been wondering if there are things like cockroaches and weeds that punish you for not playing the game long enough. If so, is there a cheat for it?

Comment: I'm uncertain if it appears in New Leaf as I haven't played it, but other versions had a ghost like character that would appear in the middle of the night and if you found him/did a favor he would remove all weeds. [here](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Wisp)

Comment: Wisp doesn't appear in this game. Just look at @George T's answer.

Comment: That's why I commented and not answered, I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weeds appear every day so if nobody pulls them out the town will be overrun, and even [Rafflesias](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Rafflesia) will appear eventually. Cockroaches will also appear in your house.
Leif at the garden store can pull all weeds if you pay him. Also, if you're the mayor and start the Beautiful Town ordinance then no weeds or cockroaches will appear and flowers will stop wilting.

Another thing is that your character's hair will become messy and you'll have to go to Shampoodle to fix it. Nothing can prevent that.

Comment: COOL! I'll set my game to "Beautiful Town".

Comment: One more thing: You'll have to go pull the weeds at least one day more after starting the ordinance, as it comes into effect the next day from when you do and only changes things from then on.

Answer (score 0):

weeds, roaches, or... worse. I have had this happen to me 4 times. A villager has moved out because of not playing in a long time. When you play it before the break, the villager is there. When you turn it back on and boot up the game, a random villager will move out, no wanings. I hope this helps. RIP Bunnie, Egbert, Hippeux, and Teddy, the villagers who moved without warning because of this.

Comment: Yep. Animal crossing Gamecube